# How to checkout a commit in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to checkout commits using the RStudio IDE? I thought double clicking on the commit history would work but it doesn't (RStudio Version 1.1.423 )

Comment: You need a lot more detail.  What have you done so far?

Comment: Staged. Committed. I can move between commits using the terminal or gitkraken, I just literally don't know where to click in RStudio

Comment: Do you want to check out a working copy at a particular commit, or just see what was done?  The former probably requires you to use the shell.  For the latter, click on the clock icon in the git tab, then click on a particular commit.

Comment: @user2554330 to check out a working copy. I know how to do it from the shell, but I just assumed there was a way to do it from the GUI

Comment: No, it's a really minimal set of commands implemented in the GUI.